# @State variable cannot be changed if initialized with a constant

Tags: swiftui

I need to start an object during the init of another one.

But this object uses a @Binding variable to a @State variable, like this:

```
struct MainView:View {

  @State var myVar = false
  private var myObject:MyObject

  init()
    let myObject($myVar)
    self.myObject = myObject
  }
```

but I cannot pass $myVar to myObject because self was not initialized alreay, so I tried to

```
struct MainView:View {

  @State var myVar = false
  private var myObject:MyObject

  init()
    let myObject(.constant(false))
    self.myObject = myObject
  }
```

This is MyObject

```
class MyObject {
  @Binding var myVar:Bool

  init(_ myVar:Binding<Bool>) }
    self._myvar = myVar
  }
```

but by doing so, myVar inside MyObject is permanently locked in the false state and cannot be changed.

How do I pass a dummy value to MyObject during initialization that does not lock the variable forever?

Comment: Why would you need view as member? Just create it in body and then passing binding to state will be ok.

Comment: what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Would you update with example of how do you use `struct MyObject:View` in the MainView's body?

Comment: sorry, MyObject is not a view, it is a class. My error. Fixed

Comment: The things you are trying to do is Wrong in many ways! 1. It is complitly bad idea to create an object in init of a View! 2. You do not need Binding in class, use Publisher. 3. The View can not work just with a class like `private var`, There is issue in most of the cases you are working! what you are trying to do? what is your goal?, maybe there is better way to do it

Comment: Is there a reason that `myVar` can't just be a `@Published` property on `MyObject` (assuming it conformed to `ObservableObject`)? That seems like it would make the problem disappear right away.

Comment: `let myObject($myVar)` is not valid syntax. Neither is `let myObject(.constant(false))`. Can you please fix your question? It would increase your odds of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the compiler accept it. But it will not work (here the `Toggle` will not move) :

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var myVar = false
    var myObject: MyObject!

    init() {
        myObject = MyObject($myVar)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myVar.description)
            Toggle("", isOn: myObject.$myVar)
        }
    }
}
```

Because it doesn't make much sense to have `myVar` (the `State`) and `myObject` (with the `Binding`) in the same view, I made two different views, a `MainView` and a `SubView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var myVar = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myVar.description)
            Toggle("MainView :", isOn: $myVar)
            SubView($myVar)
        }
        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    var myObject: MyObject

    init(_ myVar: Binding<Bool>) {
        myObject = MyObject(myVar)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myObject.myVar.description)
            Toggle("SubView :", isOn: myObject.$myVar)
        }.background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var myVar: Bool

    init(_ myVar: Binding<Bool>) {
        _myVar = myVar
    }
}
```

It is indeed a two-way Binding: the `Toggle` of the `SubView` acts on that of the `MainView` and vice versa.

Now you will have to find a use for this object. Because you could have exposed the property `myVar` (with the propertyWrapper `@Binding`) directly in the `SubView`.